# При повторных выборах фильтра клик на элементе отрабатывает 2,3,4 раз - как исправить?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, ajax, select

Есть фильтр работающий на основе стилизованного `select`, результаты работы которого передаются с помощью `ajax`.

Отрабатывает исправно, но, есть 2 момента с которыми мне не удается разобраться:

1. почему `click` на элементе списка при первом выборе отрабатывает 1 раз, а при последующих: 2,3,4 и далее раз (вывожу его в консоль). Получается и `ajax` запрос отправляется кратно данным значениям раз? как это исправить?
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Первоначальная инициализация `select` верная, но после хотя бы одного выбора, пропадает возможность выбрать теперь весь список. 
   Как сделать так, чтобы был выбор всего списка, но уже после хотя бы одного срабатывания фильтра? (т.е. в начальное состояние до работы фильтра) Надеюсь, доступно объяснил.

Вот так не правильно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так правильно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const _this = $('#categoryfilter'),
  selectOption = _this.find('option'),
  selectOptionLength = selectOption.length,
  selectedOption = selectOption.filter(':selected'),
  duration = 150; // длительность анимации 

_this.hide();
_this.wrap('<div class="selectbk"></div>');
$('<div>', {
  class: 'new-selectbk',
  text: _this.children('option:disabled').text()
}).insertAfter(_this);

const selectHead = _this.next('.new-selectbk');
$('<div>', {
  class: 'new-selectbk__list'
}).insertAfter(selectHead);

const selectList = selectHead.next('.new-selectbk__list');
for (let i = 1; i < selectOptionLength; i++) {
  $('<div>', {
      class: 'new-selectbk__item',
      html: $('<span>', {
        text: selectOption.eq(i).text()
      })
    })
    .attr('data-value', selectOption.eq(i).val())
    .appendTo(selectList);
}

const selectItem = selectList.find('.new-selectbk__item');
selectList.slideUp(0);
selectHead.on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
    $(this).addClass('on');
    selectList.slideDown(duration);

    selectItem.on('click', function() {
      let chooseItem = $(this).data('value');
      var filter = $('#filter');
      console.log(chooseItem);
      $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data: filter.serialize(),
        type: filter.attr('method'),
        success: function(data) {
          $('#result').html(data);
        }
      });
      $('select').val(chooseItem).attr('selected', 'selected');
      selectHead.text($(this).find('span').text());

      selectList.slideUp(duration);
      selectHead.removeClass('on');
    });

  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    selectList.slideUp(duration);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.selectbk {
  display: block;
  max-width: 185px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.new-selectbk {
  width: 185px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 40px 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  background: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.new-selectbk:hover {
  border: 1px solid #167dcc;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #167dcc;
  outline: none;
}

.new-selectbk:after {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #546E7A;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.new-selectbk__list {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.new-selectbk__list.on {
  display: block;
}

.new-selectbk__item span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #2b2c3e;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.new-selectbk__item span:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #167dcc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="filter.php" method="POST" id="filter">
  <select class="selectbk" name="categoryfilter" id="categoryfilter">
    <option disabled>Выбрать</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: вы при каждом клике на `selectHead` добавляете новый обработчик клика для `selectItem` вот и получаете, что с каждым разом их становится все больше и больше.

Comment: @teran спасибо, теперь второй и главный вопрос - как это поправить?

Comment: я не понял о чем там речь, что значит выбрать весь список?

Comment: @teran фильтр выбирает отдельно `javascript`, `html`, `css`
Как мне после выбора любого из них вернуться в первоначальное состояние, где отображаются сразу все из `javascript` `html`  `css`

Comment: не вижу разницы, между тем когда только запускаем список, и после нескольких попыток выбора чего-либо.

Comment: @teran перед тем как запустить список изначально выводятся все позиции `javascript` `html` `css` и есть кнопка выбора в самом верху списка. После фильтра она исчезает и теперь нет возможности восстановить изначальное состояние без перезагрузки страницы, только выбрать какую-либо из групп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже написал в комментариях, при каждом клике у вас добавляется новый обработчик, поэтому их становится все больше и больше, и выполняются они все по очереди. Так что назначение клика не элемент не надо делать в клике на сам список.

Да и в целом, на мой взгляд вы слишком увлекаетесь переменными и ручным созданием элементов, при этом не используя встроенные итераторы дочерних элементов, заменяя их классическими циклами.

Будьте проще, заведите строковый шаблон списка, и заполните его. Вы сразу видите всю верстку, это гораздо проще сопровождать, и куда нагляднее.

```js
const _this = $('#categoryfilter'),   
      duration = 150; // длительность анимации 

_this.hide();

var tpl = '<div class="selectbk">' +
            '<div class="new-selectbk"></div>'+
            '<div class="new-selectbk__list"></div>'+
          '</div>';
          
var $menu = $(tpl).insertAfter(_this);
var $list = $menu.children(".new-selectbk__list");

$menu.find(".new-selectbk")
     .text( _this.children("option:disabled").text() );


_this.children("option").each(function(idx, opt){
   var itpl= '<div class="new-selectbk__item"><span></span></div>';
   $(itpl).appendTo($list)
          .data('value',  $(opt).val() )
          .find('span')
             .text( $(opt).text() );
});

$menu.on('click', '.new-selectbk', function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('on');   
   var d = 0;
   if($(this).hasClass('on')){
       d = duration;
       
       $list.children().each(function(){
          let isCurrent = $(this).data('value') != _this.val();
          $(this).toggle(isCurrent);          
       });
   }
   //var d = $(this).hasClass('on') ? duration : 0;   
   $list.slideToggle(d);
});


$menu.on('click', '.new-selectbk__item', function(){
      let v  = $(this).data('value');
      var filter = $('#filter');
      //console.log(v);
      //$.ajax( .... );
      _this.val(v);
      $('.new-selectbk').text( $(this).text() )
                        .removeClass('on');      
      
      $list.slideUp(duration);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.selectbk {
  display: block;
  max-width: 185px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.new-selectbk {
  width: 185px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 40px 12px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  background: #fff;  
  border-radius: 0px;
  outline: none;  
  transition: all .3s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.new-selectbk:hover {
  border: 1px solid #167dcc;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #167dcc;
  outline: none;
}

.new-selectbk:after {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid #546E7A;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.new-selectbk__list {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 50;
}

.new-selectbk__list.on {
  display: block;
}

.new-selectbk__item span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #2b2c3e;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;     
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.new-selectbk__item span:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #167dcc;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="filter.php" method="POST" id="filter">
  <select class="selectbk" name="categoryfilter" id="categoryfilter">
    <option disabled>Выбрать</option>
    <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
    <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
    <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, но есть небольшое уточнение по вашему решению: первоначально строка с надписью `выбрать` не должна дублироваться в заголовке и в самом списке, только уже после выбора какой-либо из позиции появляться.

я писал сознательно в `es5`, чтобы соблюсти кроссбраузерность, это важно! (вернее здесь в примере просто не успел заменить let и const на var). Вы же пользуетесь преимуществами `es6`, но я ваш ответ зачту в любом случае

Comment: что в моем коде не работает в es5 ? разве что что строка в бэктиках.

Comment: да, шаблоны `` es5 не умеет читать

Comment: сделал без ``, особо это код не меняет.

Comment: по поводу пункта с Выбрать, у меня по этому поводу ничего нет, поскольку я просто упростил ваш код, ничего не добавляя. Хорошо бы это решить только с помощью css, но надо полагать не получится.

Comment: да, на всякий случай в вопросе указал на картинках схематично: по сути нужно, чтобы выбранный пункт не дублировался в списке. Со стилями не придумал как, буду стараться `js` докрутить

Comment: @Вася несколько подправил код, чтобы в списке не показывался текущий выбранный вариант, но это некорректно срабатывает первый раз, из-за `disabled` элемента в исходном списке.

Comment: так кстати и не понял,  речь была про текущий выбранный, или только про пункт "Выбрать".

Comment: на самом деле не столько это важно, главное пункт "Выбрать" из дубля убрать, а там уже, что проще было бы сделать

Comment: ну дак при раскрытии меню проверяйте, если значение селекта `null`, то скрывайте первый элемент, и все. У меня тут еще непонимание того. что вы вроде бы какой то кастом-плагин планируете сделать, но какое поведение ожидается, если в исходном селекте не будет пункта "Выбрать".

Comment: не-не-не, в исходном будет "Выбрать" в заголовке, а вот уже в самом списке - нет, зато при последующих итерациях должна снова появляться вверху списка, чтобы был возможно вернуться на исходную

Answer (score 1):

```
//const selectItem = selectList.find('.new-selectbk__item');
/* add */ selectList.on('click', '.new-selectbk__item', function() {
  ...
});
selectList.slideUp(0);
selectHead.on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('on')) {
    $(this).addClass('on');
    selectList.slideDown(duration);

    // remove - selectItem.on('click', function() {
    //  ...
    //});

  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('on');
    selectList.slideUp(duration);
  }
});
```

Comment: я так понимаю, что вы это имели ввиду, только 
 `selectList.on('click', '.new-selectbk__item', function() {` а не `selectHead`
https://jsfiddle.net/hq92mzcp/
работает лучше, но клик по параметру отрабатывает теперь по 2 раза всегда. Да, уже не увеличивается в геометрической прогрессии, но все еще 2 раза, а не 1